# Change an entity condition in linq

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

In the entity designer I set the conditional mapping on an entity where it filters all customers by an 'isactive' field.

That works great no problem with that, but the problem comes in my linq.

What happens when I need to set a customer to 'IsActive=false'. The property isn't mapped to my entity because the condition is mapped, but in Linq I can't find a way to change that.

```
using (var db = new CustDbConn())
{

   Customer customer= db.Customers.Single(p => p.Id == idFromEmail);
   customer.IsActive = false; //<----NOT FOUND, can not resolve 'isActive'

}
```

There has to be a way to access and change the conditions in LINQ, can someone shed some light on this? I thought about bypassing the model and just updating it using SqlCommand, but I shouldn't have to go through all that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't change model (that's you're trying to do) using LINQ query.

The only way to manipulate `IsActive` property is to bring it into `Customer` model, and throw away conditional mapping.

**UPD**.

You're misunderstanding the main purpose of conditional mapping - [inheritance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj618292).
Note, that using EF you don't work with *database tables*, you work with *entity types*. All you have, is a model. If any table field is missing from model, than yes, you can't access it via model. With reference to your question, yes, you can't change patients activity status, because *there's no activity status* in the model.

And yes, if you plan to use some sort of deletion/activity marker (like `IsActive` in you sample), you have to include it in your queries, otherwise you'll get inactive/deleted items in results. Of course, you can make helper/repository/wrapper/etc to automate it:

```
interface IEntity
{
    int Id { get; }
    bool IsActive { get; set; }
}

interface IRepository<T>
    where T : IEntity
{
    IQueryable<T> Get(bool includeInactiveEntities = false);
}
```

Comment: just to verify in case I didn't make myself clear, you're saying I can't change one of the patients active status in the table itself ever if i'm using conditional mapping? Doesn't that defeat the purpose of having a condition if it has to always be set when the database is designed or new entry is added? If I bring it back then I'd have to add 'where isactive=true' to all of the queries involving customers.

Comment: thanks for the explanation, I understand the main purpose of conditional mapping. And I'd like to keep it, so I dont have to include it in every query, I think the best solution is to change the value in the database directly using SqlCommand update in this case and bypass the model.